# Signature RSA for data with length as key length

Tags: java, key, rsa

I have to create a signature from given data, but the problem is that data has length as key length. All implementation of RSA Signers in JAVA allow to put data of max. key length minus one length. How to create signature for data with length as key length? Algorithm is basic RSA without padding and without digest.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please don't use RSA without padding - it's a terrible idea and **[diminishes the security of your system](http://rdist.root.org/2009/10/06/why-rsa-encryption-padding-is-critical/)**.

If you need to sign data that is equal in size to your key length (or larger), I'm afraid you'll need to use a digest. There's not really a choice here. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to use a digest anyway.

Comment: OK thanks for reply. The thing is that I write PKCS11 library and I have to implement RSA without padding too. I found something in Documentation of PKCS11 - when some application is calling sign function with RSA no padding algorithm and data has length equal in size to key and first byte is 0 then i should use a special algorithm defined in documentation to obtain data for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

RSA is only able to encrypt data to a maximum amount of your key size (2048 bits = 256 bytes) minus padding / header data (11 bytes for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding).

As a result it is often not possible to encrypt files with RSA directly. RSA is also not meant for this purpose. If you want to encrypt more data, you can use something like:

```
Generate a 256-bit random keystring K
Encrypt your data with AES-CBC with K
Encrypt K with RSA
Send both to the other side
```